# Oracle APEX - Moving multiple pages to a new App

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

Running the current version of Oracle APEX. Looking for best practices / sanity check for extracting/moving a “module” to a new app.

I have an app in a Workspace. This app has around 70 pages, 5 of which go to a specific "module" / functionality. I want to extract/move this module to a new/not yet created app within the same workspace. This new application WILL need it's own administration page. Never having done this before, I want to make sure I get this right. Because of the amount of Javascript involved, I need to keep the page numbers the same. There are no private reports, only public reports.

Expected steps:

1). Create a new app in the same workspace, with Administration page

2). Do I export the whole app, and only import those pages I am wanting? (Is this even supported?). Do I have to export page at a time, etc. then import?

3). Update user access on the Administration page.

4). Update menu structure

What is the best/proper approach to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd probably

- export current application
- import it (either choose new ID, or let Apex set it)
- new application should work just the same as the original
- remove all pages you don't need

  - in App Builder, click the "Utilities" icon
  - on the right hand side of the screen, under "Page Specific Utilities", choose "Cross Page Utilities"
  - choose "Delete multiple pages"
  - mark checkbox for pages you don't need
  - click "Delete pages" button
- run the application
- check how it looks and - if necessary - fix whatever might be needed